# How fast does methane rise in atmosphere?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, atmospheric-science, buoyancy

[Archimedes' principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle) states that the upward buoyant force that is exerted on a body immersed in a fluid, whether fully or partially, is equal to the weight of the fluid that the body displaces.

If the methane was in a balloon you can calculate the buoyancy force by doing $$F = (\text{volume}\cdot\text{density of air}\cdot g) -  (\text{volume}\cdot\text{density of methane}\cdot g)$$ Then get the acceleration and calculate a velocity, but how would you do that calculation if it was coming from the ocean or another source on the ground?

Comment: Are you asking about the acceleration methane will experience due to buoyant force, or are you asking about how fast it will end up rising? Because those questions have different answers.

Comment: how fast it will end up rising. I thought they would be related, but maybe not

Comment: This is a really hard question to answer, because while you have the right equation for the net force acting on the methane at rest, air resistance comes into play once the methane is moving, and that's really difficult to calculate. Usually people just find that bit out in experiments or computer simulations. All I can say is that the ultimate speed the methane will rise at depends on the amount of methane you have.

Comment: It would be a transport and dispersion situation on the global scale.  The atmospheric scientists have parameterized the dispersion process, and are able to make accurate predictions of the methane concentration as a function of altitude.  Note also that methane reacts chemically with hydroxyl radical in the atmosphere, which limits its lifetime in the atmosphere.